# Can I travel to Germany on a bus through France with a "Deutschland" visa not a Schengen stated visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, france

I have been issued a German family reunion visa type D. it clearly states that the visa is for Germany and not Schengen states as I used to get in the past. Can I travel by bus from London through France to Germany with this visa?

Comment: Note that this visa entitles you to travel through (and even visit for a short time) France, Belgium and other countries in the Schengen Area, but you'll need a separate visa for the UK.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**.  While I can't find anything useful on a German site, family reunion (type D) visas are issued by all Schengen states, and the [French foreign ministry site](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/getting-a-visa/article/what-type-to-apply-for) says:

> *Long-stay visas*
>
> The long-stay visa is not a Schengen visa ; it is a
>   national visa that entitles you, whatever the reason for your stay, to
>   live in France for more than three months.
>
> **The visa also entitles you
>   to transit through another country in the Schengen Area on your way to
>   France and to move freely throughout the Schengen Area for its entire
>   period of validity.**
>
> The main reasons for issuing this type of visa are
>   study, work and family reunion.